# Integral: $\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{1+4x^2}{\rm d}x$ [Other method type question.]

Tags: integration

> Integral: $$I=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{1+4x^2}{\rm d}x$$

One thing to quickly do it take $y=2x$:
$$I=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+y)}{1+y^2}{\rm d}y$$
I took $y=\tan z$:
$$I=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/4}\ln(1+\tan z){\rm d}z$$
Now substitute $u=\pi/4-z$:
$$I=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/4}[\ln2-\ln(1+\tan z)]{\rm d}z=\frac\pi8\ln2-I\\I=\frac\pi{16}\ln 2$$
Any other methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}I &= \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1 + y)}{1 + y^2}\, dy\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{y}{(1 + ry)(1 + y^2)}\, dr\, dy\\
& = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{y}{(1 + ry)(1 + y^2)}\, dy\, dr\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{r}{(1 + r^2)(1 + y^2)} + \frac{y}{(1 + r^2)(1 + y^2)}- \frac{r}{(1 + r^2)(1 + ry)}\right)\, dy\, dr\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{r}{1 + r^2}\cdot \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{1}{2(1 + r^2)}\ln(2) - \frac{\ln(1 + r)}{1 + r^2}\right)\, dr\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\ln(2) + \frac{\pi}{8}\ln(2)\right) - I\\
&= \frac{\pi}{8}\ln(2) - I
\end{align}

So $2I = \frac{\pi}{8}\ln(2)$, or $$I = \frac{\pi}{16}\ln(2).$$

Comment: is this a standard technique or related to some method?

Comment: @ADG what do you mean "or related to some method"? I think this is somewhat standard, but not used often.

Comment: ok i didn't knew about it since I never read a standard book...

Comment: @ADG I'm not sure if its standard, but I'm sure books like Schaum's Outlines will have this method recorded.

Comment: thanks i'll read it in my pleaseure time.

Comment: nice. how or what made you think of this way of evaluating the integral?

Comment: @abel experience I guess, but the presence of $\ln(1 + y)$ in the integrand made me think of representing it as the integral of a rational function, so the problem will be translated to computing a double integral of rational expression, which tends to be easier to solve.

Answer (score 4):

Once we have:
$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+y)}{1+y^2}\,dy$$
we can set $y=\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ in order to have:
$$ I = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\log\frac{2z}{z+1}}{(z-1)^2+(z+1)^2}\,dz=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log\frac{2}{z+1}}{2z^2+2}\,dz=\frac{\pi}{8}\log 2-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(z+1)}{z^2+1}\,dz$$
or:
$$ 2I = \frac{\pi}{8}\log 2\implies I = \frac{\pi}{16}\log 2$$
just as you got.

Comment: I suppose that is another way of substituting $y\mapsto\tan x$ and $x\mapsto\pi/4-x$ in a single step??

Comment: @ADG: yes, it is.

Comment: don't you know spaces in latex are not shown as you used in `I<space>=<space>\frac...`